# How to print all enum values in Java?

Tags: java, enums

```
enum generalInformation {
    NAME {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Name";
        }
    },
    EDUCATION {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Education";
        }
    },
    EMAIL {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Email";
        }
    },
    PROFESSION {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Profession";
        }
    },
    PHONE {
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Phone";
        }
    }
}
```

I have that information are avaiable in enum.

1. How to print all enum values like: `print.generalInformation`?

That outputs:

> Name
>   Education
>   Email
>   Phone

2. How to pass that enum `generalInformation` as an arg in another function?

Comment: You don't have to override `toString` method in each enum element. Every enum have method name() that returns String representation of element that invoked this method: `SomeEnum.VALUE.name()` will return "VALUE" String. You can just `return name().charAt(0)+name().substring(1).toLowerCase();` in your main `toString()` like here http://ideone.com/IraxgB.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(generalInformation.values()));
```

Your second part... Just the same as an `interface` or a `class`

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, I would refactor your enum to pass the string representation in a constructor parameter. That code is at the bottom.

Now, to print all enum values you'd just use something like:

```
// Note: enum name changed to comply with Java naming conventions
for (GeneralInformation info : EnumSet.allOf(GeneralInformation.class)) {
    System.out.println(info);
}
```

An alternative to using `EnumSet` would be to use `GeneralInformation.values()`, but that means you have to create a new array each time you call it, which feels wasteful to me. Admittedly calling `EnumSet.allOf` requires a new object each time too... if you're doing this a *lot* and are concerned about the performance, you could always cache it somewhere.

You can use `GeneralInformation` just like any other type when it comes to parameters:

```
public void doSomething(GeneralInformation info) {
    // Whatever
}
```

Called with a value, e.g.

```
doSomething(GeneralInformation.PHONE);
```

---

**Refactoring using a constructor parameter**

```
public enum GeneralInformation {
    NAME("Name"),
    EDUCATION("Education"),
    EMAIL("Email"),
    PROFESSION("Profession"),
    PHONE("Phone");

    private final String textRepresentation;

    private GeneralInformation(String textRepresentation) {
        this.textRepresentation = textRepresentation;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
         return textRepresentation;
    }
}
```

With your *current* values, you could actually just convert the name to title case automatically - but that wouldn't be very flexible for the long term, and I think this explicit version is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Since **Java 8** I would suggest the following solution:

```
public static String printAll() {
    return Stream.of(GeneralInformation.values()).
                map(GeneralInformation::name).
                collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

Comment: In this function, how can we pass `GeneralInformation` as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In applications, it's good practice to separate data from presentation.  It allows the data to be used in different user interfaces, it makes the data objects more lightweight, and it allows for the future possibility of [internationalization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/).

With that in mind, it's good to avoid strongly coupling the display name to the enum constant.  Fortunately, there is a class which makes this easy:  EnumMap.

```
public class ApplicationUI {
    private final Map<GeneralInformation, String> names;

    public ApplicationUI() {
        names = new EnumMap<>(GeneralInformation.class);

        names.put(GeneralInformation.NAME,       "Name");
        names.put(GeneralInformation.EDUCATION,  "Education");
        names.put(GeneralInformation.EMAIL,      "Email");
        names.put(GeneralInformation.PROFESSION, "Profession");
        names.put(GeneralInformation.PHONE,      "Phone");

        assert names.keySet().containsAll(
            EnumSet.allOf(GeneralInformation.class)) :
            "Forgot to add one or more GeneralInformation names";
    }

    public String getNameFor(GeneralInformation info) {
        return names.get(info);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still on Java 1.7 this is what worked for me:

```
String genInfoValues = "";
boolean firstRun = true;
for (generalInformation info : generalInformation.values()){
    if (firstRun) {
        firstRun = false;
        genInfoValues += info.name();
    } else {
        genInfoValues += ", " + info.name();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

values() on the enum returns an array. So, it would be simple to do the following to:

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(generalInformation.values()));