# Can't seem to print an arraylist full of objects/enums

Tags: java, arrays, printing, arraylist, enums

I was trying to create a card game golf for fun and to practice my java skills.  I'm trying to use enums for my card values and suites.  Those values are held in a constructor, named Card, in the Card Class.

The problem I'm running into to is printing my arraylist Deck that holds all my individual cards.  This method can be found in the DeckOfCards Class . I want to see if my program is creating a full deck of cards.  Thanks in advance for the help!

DeckOfCards Class

```
package finalProjectGolf;
    // Deck class represent a deck of playing cards.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DeckOfCards {


    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>(); //array of Card objects

    private int currentCard; // index of next Card to be dealt (0-51)
    private static int numDecks = 1;

    public int getCurrentCard() {
        return currentCard;
    }

    public void setCurrentCard(int currentCard) {
        this.currentCard = currentCard;
    }

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52 * numDecks; //constant # of Cards


    //constructor fill deck of Cards
    public DeckOfCards(){

        currentCard = 0; //set currentCard so first Card dealt is deck[0]

        //Card Index
            int c = 0;
        //for each deck
                for (int d = 0; d < numDecks; d++){
                    //for each suit
                    for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++){
                        // for each number
                        for (int n = 1; n <= 13; n++){
                            //add a new card to the deck
                            deck.add(new Card(CardValue.values()[n],Suit.values()[s]));   //when using Enums java makes arrays automatically and you can use them by .values()
                            c++;    
                        }}}//end for loop
    }//end DeckOfCards constructor

    //shuffle deck of Cards with one-pass algorithm
    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    public int points(){
        int value = deck.get(currentCard).getCardValue().getCardValue();
        return value;
    }

    //deal one Card
    public Card dealCard(int currentCard) {

        //determine whether Cards remain to be dealt
        if( currentCard < deck.size() ){
            return deck.get(currentCard); //return current Card in array
        }
        else
            return null; // return null to indicate that all Cards were dealt
    }//end method dealCard


    public void printDeck(){
        {
            currentCard = 0; //set currentCard so first Card dealt is deck[0]

            //Card Index
                int c = 0;
            //for each deck
                    for (int d = 0; d < numDecks; d++){
                        //for each suit
                        for (int s = 0; s < 4; s++){
                            // for each number
                            for (int n = 1; n <= 13; n++){
                                //add a new card to the deck
                                System.out.printf("");   //when using Enums java makes arrays automatically and you can use them by .values()
                                c++;    
                            }}}//end for loop
        }//end DeckOfCards constructor

    }
}// end class DeckOfCards
```

Card Class

```
package finalProjectGolf;


public class Card
{
      private Suit suit;
      private CardValue cardValue;


      public Card (CardValue cardValue, Suit suit) //constructor of Card, holds Card value and it's suit
      {
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
        this.suit = suit;

      }

      public Suit getSuit()
      {
        return suit;
      }

      public void setSuit(Suit suit)
      {
        this.suit = suit;
      }

      public CardValue getCardValue()
      {
        return cardValue;
      }

      public void setCardValue(CardValue cardValue)
      {
        this.cardValue = cardValue;
      }

      public String toString(){
            return  cardValue + " of " + suit;
        }// end method toString


    }
```

CardValue Class

```
package finalProjectGolf;


    public enum CardValue
    {
      ACE(1),
      TWO(2),
      THREE(3),
      FOUR(4),
      FIVE(5),
      SIX(6),
      SEVEN(7),
      EIGHT(8),
      NINE(9),
      TEN(10),
      JACK(11),
      QUEEN(12),
      KING(13);

      private int cardValue;

      private CardValue (int value)
      {
        this.cardValue = value;
      }

      public int getCardValue() {
        return cardValue;
      }
    }
```

Suit Class

```
package finalProjectGolf;

public enum Suit
{
  HEARTS(1),
  SPADES(2),
  CLUBS(3),
  DIAMONDS(4);

  private int suit;

  private Suit (int value)
  {
    this.suit = value;
  }

  public int getCardSuit() {
    return suit;
  }
}
```

Comment: And the problem is... By the way, why didn't you override the `toString` method in all your classes/enums as well?

Answer (score 2):

To add to AaronB's answer, your printDeck method is in fact wrong, as you have posted it. Currently it prints the empty string 52 times. In addition, you don't need to triple for loop just to print all the items in your deck. A very simple implementation that prints each card on a new line for a single deck would be:

```
public void printDeck() {
    for(Card card : deck) {
        System.out.println( card.toString() );
    }
}
```

You also need to override the toString method for your enum values so that they print the name you want. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14413605/1425014 for how to do that.

Your main class is called DeckOfCards. That indicates to me that the class represents a single deck of cards. However, judging by `for (int d = 0; d < numDecks; d++)` and `private static int numDecks = 1`, it appears that you intend for DeckOfCards to represent one or more decks of cards. It may be clearer to simply uses a collection (such as ArrayList) if you need more than on DeckOfCards instead of complicating the DeckOfCards class.

Finally, you should try to make sure your comments make sense before you post your code here. The comments for your printDeck() function haven't been changed after you copy/pasted from the DeckOfCards constructor.

Comment: Great comments, thanks for checking the print method as well. 

@anonymous: A lot of newer programmers tend to get too caught up in specific syntax; taking a step back and thinking it through logically and slowly is a really important part of making any high-quality piece of code. "Do I really need to do this? Does this make sense?" should always be going through your head as you plan and code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that your `printDeck` method doesn't work (I haven't tested it yet, but at first glance it looks reasonable), it's that you never call it. You could place it at the end of the DeckOfCards constructor, if the point is to check that it's all there correctly.

In addition, you really should refactor a bunch of your logic, most notably in the DeckOfCards class. You've got some big blocks of computation -- put that in a method. Also, instead of declaring variables in the class, you should declare them in the constructor. For example:

```
ArrayList<Card> deck; //array of Card objects

private int currentCard; // index of next Card to be dealt (0-51)
private static int numDecks;

//constructor fill deck of Cards
public DeckOfCards(int numDecks){
    deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    currentCard = 0; //set currentCard so first Card dealt is deck[0]
    this.numDecks = numDecks;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong though, you didn't really describe what the issue was...

Comment: There were several issues and your advice did help a lot, thanks!