# Print enum list with brackets and commas

Tags: java

I can print my enum list using a for each loop, it prints nice and clean. But I want to print it with the brackets and commas in beteween each element. Here is what i tried and the output produced. How can I produce the brackets and commas? [SU, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA]

```
public class ExerciseLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Day fDay = Day.SU;

        System.out.println("F day: " + fDay);
        System.out.print("All days ");

        for (Day el : Day.values()) {
            System.out.print(el+ " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(Day.values());
    }

    public enum Day {
        SU, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA;
    } 
}
```

#### Ouput

```
F day: SU
All days SU MO TU WE TH FR SA 
[LExerciseLoop$Day;@15db9742
```

Comment: what does `el + " "` print out? What can you do to change this so that it prints out a comma?

Comment: I see what you are trying to tell me, i can enter a comma in between the spaces and i will output correctly. But the brackets will repeat with every iterarion, so i will end up with a [ ] in between each element

Comment: Try `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(Day.values()));`

Comment: "But the brackets will repeat with every iteration" - perhaps instead of printing the brackets as part of the iteration, only do it at the beginning/end?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that worked just fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to print all enum value in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413581/how-to-print-all-enum-value-in-java)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Or even `System.out.println(EnumSet.allOf(Day.class))`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do so. First a manual approach:

```
// Build the text
final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
result.append("[");
for (final Day el : Day.values()) {
    result.append(el).append(", ");
}
// Remove the extra ", "
result.setLength(result.length() - 2);
result.append("]");
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Of course you can evade the "removement" of the extra **", "** by simply adding a counter. If the last element is reached, don't add it.

However I'd like to show you a new class (from Java 8) which was made exact for this purpose, the **StringJoiner**!

```
final StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
for (final Day el : Day.values()) {
    result.add(el.toString());
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

You can find more information in the documentation: [JavaAPI#StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)

Comment: +1; Alternatively to `StringJoiner` you could use `String s = Arrays.stream(Day.values()).collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]"));` which uses one internally.